# She declared herself extremely hurt by his lack of support. (hurt is an adjective or past participle?)

Tags: parts-of-speech

> She declared herself extremely **hurt** by his lack of support.

'hurt' is used as a verb, adjective, or even as a noun

What's the part of speech?

Comment: An adjective as objective complement of "declared". Compare the subjective complement of "was" in "She was extremely hurt by his lack of support",

Comment: It's the same meaning as "She declared herself to be extremely hurt by his lack of support", where "to be" is functioning as a copula with the adjective "hurt".